# Setting a dynamic field in Ohm / Redis

Tags: ruby, redis, ohm

How do I set a field dynamically for a Ohm object?

```
class OhmObj < Ohm::Model
  attribute :foo
  attribute :bar
  attribute :baz

  def add att, val
    self[att] = val
  end
end

class OtherObj

  def initialize
    @ohm_obj = OhmObj.create
  end

  def set att, val
    @ohm_obj[att] = val #doesn't work
    @ohm_obj.add(att, val) #doesn't work
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`attribute` class method from `Ohm::Model`](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/Ohm/Model.html#attribute-class_method) defines accessor and mutator methods for the named attribute:

```
def self.attribute(name)
  define_method(name) do
    read_local(name)
  end

  define_method(:"#{name}=") do |value|
    write_local(name, value)
  end

  attributes << name unless attributes.include?(name)
end
```

So when you say `attribute :foo`, you get these methods for free:

```
def foo         # Returns the value of foo.
def foo=(value) # Assigns a value to foo.
```

You could use [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) to call the mutator method like this:

```
@ohm_obj.send((att + '=').to_sym, val)
```

If you really want to say `@ohm_obj[att] = val` then you could add something like the following to your `OhmObj` class:

```
def []=(att, value)
    send((att + '=').to_sym, val)
end
```

And you'd probably want the accessor version as well to maintain symmetry:

```
def [](att)
    send(att.to_sym)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]` and `[]=` as a dynamic attribute accessor and mutator are defined by default in Ohm::Model in Ohm 0.2.