# How do you push an element onto a list dynamically in Redis/Ohm?

Tags: ruby, redis, ohm

This is a follow-up to this question: [Setting a dynamic field in Ohm / Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638375/setting-a-dynamic-field-in-ohm-redis/6638584#6638584)

I'm unable to find the method that I can use with the send() method, to dynamically be able to add an object to an unknown list.  I tried adding this method to the Ohm::Model class:

```
def add_to_list(name, obj)
    send((name.to_s + '<<').to_sym, obj)
end
h.add_to_list(:player_ids, OhmSeat.create(seat_number: 5, value: 6))
```

But I get

```
undefined method `player_ids<<'
```

There is a rpush method, but I can't seem to call it directly. and this doesn't work:

```
h.player_ids.rpush(OhmSeat.create(seat_number: 5, value: 6))
```

Comment: Is `player_ids<<` a valid method name? You aren't meaning `foo.player_ids.<<`, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andrew Grimm mentioned, you should do:

```
def add_to_list(name, obj)
  send(name) << obj
end
```

or just do:

```
h.player_ids << OhmSeat.create(...)
```